# Is the document in Chrome the same as the Interface Document in the whatwg specification?

Tags: javascript, html

When I use console.dir(document) in Chrome devtools,I can not find getElementByTagName on it.
[image]
But the Standard defined getElementByTagName on document interface.

Here is the Standard: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-document.

Another question is: If they are different,Then why they have many properties in the same.Like compatMode、contentType and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quirk of how `console.dir()` works in Chrome. It prints accessor properties, but not methods. To see the methods, you need to use a different invocation, such as

```js
console.log(Document.prototype);
```

Comment: That's both a more accurate and a simpler explanation than what I was going for. I'll  delete my answer 