# What exactly is an interface?

Tags: javascript, interface

Im reading JavaScript Eloquent which keeps mentioning "interfaces" in chapter 6 but i cant get my head around what it exactly is, this is the books first mention of interfaces

> Different pieces of such a program interact with each other through interfaces, limited sets of functions or bindings that provide useful functionality at a more abstract level, hiding their precise implementation.

this makes me think if it is like methods for objects/classes or methods for arrays like `.join()`?

Another time it mentions it in the getters & setters section

> Interfaces often consist mostly of methods, but it is also okay to include properties that hold non-function values. For example, Map objects have a size property that tells you how many keys are stored in them.

I realise i could google but i cant find an answer that helps me understand how this book uses it.

Comment: Sounds like you could read it as anything which is available for public consumption on the provided object or its instances - any property of the object accessible to other code

Comment: https://www.webreflection.co.uk/blog/2016/03/23/javascript-interfaces. (QUOTE: An interface is usually a behavior described through methods or properties.

Interfaces can be used to simply describe expectations: they don’t need to implement any logic at all.

As an example, the following is a partial Human class described through the amount of interfaces it implements.)

Comment: An interface is a contract that defines what an object can have as a property and what that properties do. Based on this, other part of code can communicate with this object using one of the pre-defined property. However, interface is a theoretical term and there is nothing called interface in JS. You can define in Typescript or other higher level languages

Comment: Apparently, they use "interface" to mean [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface).

Comment: For 10K+ there is [this interesting comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57942567/is-the-document-in-chrome-the-same-as-the-interface-document-in-the-whatwg-speci/57951425#comment102314678_57942737) by @domenic (from whatwg) about why *they* use the term "interface".  Basically, relics from CORBA, you can see it as a synonym for class.

Comment: @Kaiido reposting: "*> "The whatwg spec calls it the Document interface for a reason: an interface describes features something must have to be a Document according to the standard, but nothing prevents an object from doing more."  This is incorrect. "interface" is used because we use an abstraction layer, Web IDL, which was originally defined for CORBA. This leads to a variety of strange terms: interface <-> class, readonly attribute <-> get accessor property, attribute <-> get/set accessor property, etc.  Browsers cannot do more than the standard describes, generally speaking*"

Comment: @Kaiido also, enlightening, in fact. There are all sorts of little tidbids and factoids tucked away in comments all across SO. I wish there was a way to index them in some fashion.